# How to make a custom UserList control in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, custom-controls

I'm making a chat program and I need a UserList control that supports icons, names, banners, status icons.

Here is a picture of the UserList I wish to clone:

[image]

As you can see the user name appears on top of the background image.

The status at the far shows red for admins, yellow for members and so on.

There are 2 more status icons that appear BEFORE the admin/member status and they show if a user is accepting private chats/messages here is a picture of that:

[image]

As you can see the UserList can contain normal (non banner like) icons as well as chat/pm status.

The UserList must scroll like any normal listview type control.

So can somebody tell me how to produce this control in C# winforms or wpf?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If using WPF, I would start by looking into an `ItemsControl`. It's a control that you can bind to a collection of items, and it will loop through those items and draw each one according to whatever Template you gave it. Since you want Scroll behavior, I would recommend wrapping it in a `ScrollViewer`. If you want Selection behavior as well (not mentioned), you will probably want to use a ListBox instead, and override the Template to specify your own. That should be enough to point you in the right direction if you choose to use WPF - Google has plenty of examples of all these things :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WPF, start with a ListView and set the view to a GridView.
Then set up the columns and cell templates.
Bind to properties.

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
     <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                       <Image Source="{Binding UserIcon}"/>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Status">
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Image Source="{StaticResource PrivateChatImage}" Visibility="{Binding IsPrivateChat, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                       <Image Source="{StaticResource PrivateMessImage}" Visibility="{Binding IsPrivateMess, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                       <Image Source="{Binding StatusIcon}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

Comment: How would you do that programatically?

Comment: XAML tags are .NET objects and the attributes are the properties of the objects so just create the objects above in code...like `ListView view = new ListView(); view.Margin =` and so on. It is much easier to do with XAML though.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for trying to help out you lot.

I did however manage to solve the problem by custom drawing everything.

Here is the end result
http://q67.imgup.net/Untitledeb8d.png

Bascially what I did was make a WinForms UserControl then added a userList class so it hooked into OnPaint() then looped through and drew the users.

It worked fairly well so then I made a header for it with Name and Status then I made the seperator grabbable to move it around (since its drawn on it has to be all manual stuff). It properly sets the cursor to the splitter.

After that was finished I needed a way to know what user a person clicked on but that was just a simple rect search.

After that was complete I needed a scroll that worked so I moved the user paintings into a new class that inherits SplitterControl I believe and then I made it set it's scroll size based on how many users in the list * how big the elements are etc.

All in all this userlist seems to work just as good as the one I was trying to clone.

So all is well!.